# jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler

Tags: javascript, webdriver, jmeter

I am using javascript in JMETER to access the webpage through jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler. And this is my script,

```
WDS.browser.get('http://login.salesforce.com')
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var username = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('username'))
username.sendKeys(['prakash93@salesforce.com'])
var password = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('password'))
password.sendKeys(['**********'])
var Login = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('Login'))
Login.click()
var Account_Tab = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('Account_Tab'))
Account_Tab.click()
```

Every thing is fine while I am running script up to this . After this I have to click a link and page should be navigate to that link which doesn't have id. So I can't edit the script after this. I have extracted xpath of that link by using mozilla's FirePath which follows below,

```
.//*[@id='bodyCell']/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/th/a
```

can anyone help to run the script to access that page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not limited by this "Id" selector only, you should be able to use any selector described in [org.openqa.selenium.By](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) class.

I wouldn't recommend using XPath generated by extensions as it looks shitty, fragile and it is not obvious what link you are trying to click, I would rather go for [By.ByLinkText()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByLinkText.html) method like:

```
var myLink = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.linkText("your_link_text_here"))
```

or if you want the XPath:

```
var myLink = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//a[text()='your_link_text_here')"))
```

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)